# how to detect item in array

Tags: php, api

i working with coda.io API. i never use API before and i want to print all the data but coda limit the data with 200 data on each page. every page has "nextPageToken" to access the next page.

i have idea to print the page and then if the page has "nextPageToken" print the data on the next page. but i don't know how to make that condition. when "nextPageToken" not exist on the last page and to merge all the array that each page makes.

```
    $coda = new CodaPHP\CodaPHP(CODA_TOKEN);
    $result = $coda->listRows(CODA_DOC_ID, CODA_TABLE_ID);
    $items = [];
    $pageToken = '';

    while ($result["nextPageToken"]) {
        $result = $coda->listRows(CODA_DOC_ID, CODA_TABLE_ID, [
            'nextPageToken' => $result["nextPageToken"]
        ]);

        var_dump(sizeof($result));
    }
```

Comment: Add the actual items this returns to `$items` then each time? Where is the problem with that?

Comment: assuming $result is an array, whenever you get $result, $items += $result;

Comment: @AnuratChapanond it appears to be an array, but not a pure data array - if `$result["nextPageToken"]` indicates whether there are more result pages, then it will probably have a property on that same level, that is the actual data array.